# Wall heater wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm putting in a 2000 watt 240volt wall heater that calls for 14gage wire with a 15 amp circuit breaker. There is an existing 12gage wire with a 20amp 240volt circuit breaker not being used. Can I just use that?

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel?

Answer (score 1):

Using 12 AWG wire for a 15A circuit is just fine. However, if the device calls specifically for a 15A breaker then you **must** use a 15A breaker. You can't upsize the circuit just to save a few $. That means replacing the 20A breaker with a 15A breaker. Note also that the breaker needs to be a double-breaker or a handle-tied pair of breakers, not just 2 single 15A breakers side-by-side.

Comment: Being a 240V-only load, a handle-tied pair would suffice, but even if you had the spare 15A breakers, running around to find a listed handle-tie would be a chore.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica And I just checked homedepot.com (I know your feelings about Home Depot, but it is super easy to look up stuff online) and it is typically < $2 extra for a double vs. 2 singles.

Comment: Yeah, I use HD for that too.  Their catalog is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the breaker to a 15 AMP breaker but you can use the #12 AWG wire. This is because the manufacturer has stated the requirement of a 15 AMP breaker

Comment: Does the manufacturer require a dedicated circuit, though?  Let's see, 2000W = 8.33A, provision to 10.416... there's room for 4.6A of more stuff.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   Install an 11 AMP breaker... OH SNAP!! they don't make an 11 AMP breaker